# How do Bonuspell 1 and 2 work?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I have added the Bonuspell (receive an extra spell when crafting) and Bonuspell 2 (receive 2 extra spells when crafting) in the Magic Ascension Tree.

My understanding is that after I craft a Magic spell that I would receive 2 additional magic of the same type in 2 magic flasks.

For example, I have 3 Magic Flasks. I craft a Thunder spell. After crafting, it will fill a Magic flask plus 2 (Bonuspell 2) of the same spell.

However, when I do the above I only get 1 spell which is the spell I crafted. The spell is not duplicated with the ability I purchased.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting what Bonuspell does.

It doesn't fill an extra *flask* of that spell, rather, it grants you an extra *use* of that spell in that flask. If you'd normally get 3, you'll have 4, etc.

The post [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5gzm9q/what_does_bonuspell_do_exactly/?client=safari) confirms this:

> Just gives you one extra use of a spell you make (or 2 for the upgrade).

Comment: Wow. That  makes me upset that I've farmed AP that long for such a stupid ability. Thanks for clarifying that. I had some Zu Beaks and thought that the reason I was getting so many usage spells is because that item is hard to come by but come to find out is was because of the ability I have. Oh well.

Comment: @Aspire27 yeah I left out the rest of the passage I'd quoted. It was basically saying the ability was useless.

Comment: As strong as magic is and can be, for healing, exp gaining or pure dmg, i dont agree 2 extra casts is useless. It is, however, WAY too expensive for its benefit.